# nx React/Next.js shared type declaration file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a [nx](https://nx.dev/) Next.js app within my workspace, I'm using [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/) so I created a `styled.d.ts` file for the type declarations of my theme, as describe on the [docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#create-a-declarations-file). I placed it on the root of my `app` and works as expected:

```
workspace
└── apps
    └── app
        └── styled.d.ts
```

But now, I created a components library and want to use my theme type definitions over there, so I copied `styled.d.ts` to `libs/`:

```
workspace
├── apps
│   └── app
│       └── styled.d.ts
└── libs
    └── components-library
        └── styled.d.ts
```

This works and I have my theme type definitions both on the app and on the components library, but I'm duplicating the file. I tried placing it on the root of the workspace but did not work.

Any ideas on how to share `styled.d.ts` without duplicating it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We are also using styled components with a types declaration file. To use it across multiple apps and libs we have created a folder `types` on the root level. Inside there we place the declaration files. For example `types/styled-components/index.d.ts`.

Next go to your `tsconfig.lib.json` and `tsconfig.app.json`. Inside extend the `files` section for the new types:

```
  "files": [
    "...",
    "../../types/styled-components/index.d.ts",
  ],
```